# QueryOver find alias string

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the next aggregation query:

```
   IQueryOver<CustomerTask, CustomerTask> query = GetSession().QueryOver(() => task)
    .JoinAlias(() => task.TaskList, () => taskList)
    .JoinAlias(() => task.TaskChain, () => taskChain)
    .Where(() => taskList.SalesFlow == salesFlow)
    .Select(
        Projections.Group(() => taskList.Id)
            .WithAlias(() => salesFlowTaskStatisticsGridRow.RowId),
        Projections.Group(() => taskList.SalesFlow.Id)
            .WithAlias(() => salesFlowTaskStatisticsGridRow.SalesFlowId),
        Projections.Group(() => taskList.Name).WithAlias(() => salesFlowTaskStatisticsGridRow.Name),
        // ReSharper disable ExpressionIsAlwaysNull
        criteriaBuilder.FindAverageCompletionTime(salesFlowTaskStatisticsGridRow)
    // ReSharper restore ExpressionIsAlwaysNull
    ).TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<SalesFlowTaskStatisticsGridRow>());
```

Since counting average time requires calling datediff function to write it I use SqlProjection

```
    private static AggregateProjection CountAverageCompletionTimeForTasksCriteria()
    {
        return Projections.Avg(Projections
            .SqlProjection("datediff(ss, Created, CompletedDate) as CompletionTimeInSeconds",
                new[] {"CompletionTimeInSeconds"}, new[] {NHibernateUtil.Double}));
    }
```

The problem is that both **Task** and **TaskChain** have the same names for **Created** and **CompletedDate** properties, so I need to pass an alias. But I cannot manage to get the string alias to form a correct sql projection. Is there a way to get these aliases or could I stick in the **datediff** function into the query in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate doesn't provide a lot of sophisticated options for dealing with aliases when using SqlProjection.

The only workaround is to profile the query first without the datediff projection, and see what aliases NHibernate is using for the Task and TaskChain (they will probably be something like *this_* and *this_1*). You can then manually hardcode these alias into the projection like this:

```
.SqlProjection("datediff(ss, this_.Created, this_.CompletedDate) as CompletionTimeInSeconds",
                new[] {"CompletionTimeInSeconds"}, new[] {NHibernateUtil.Double})
```

Obviously this is far from perfect, but it will work.